# yum + option for yum update fallback

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum

Someone did a `yum update` on my Linux machine:

```
 yum history list 27
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
ID     | Command line             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    27 | update                   | 2018-01-22 13:34 | Update         |    5 EE
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
```

is any option for yum update fallback ?

```
yum history list all   ( see 27 )
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
ID     | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    30 | root <root>              | 2018-01-23 16:18 | Reinstall      |    1 EE
    29 | root <root>              | 2018-01-23 16:17 | Reinstall      |    1
    28 | root <root>              | 2018-01-23 16:17 | Reinstall      |    1
    27 | root <root>              | 2018-01-22 13:34 | Update         |    5 E<
```

Comment: Look into using "yum history rollback"